# Testing an R package against a Julia package on github actions - works on all OS but fails on windows

Tags: r, julia, github-actions

This is a cross-post from the [rstudio forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/testing-an-r-package-against-a-julia-package-on-github-actions-works-on-all-os-but-fails-on-windows/124349).

I have been working towards continuous integration testing of an algorithm wrapped in an R package against a Julia implementation, which I have also packaged in an R package via JuliaConnectoR.

I create a standard cmd-check workflow via `usethis::use_github_actions()`, but additionally install Julia, the required Julia package (WildBootTests.jl) and link R and Julia (the 'JULIA_BINDIR' part).

The code below successfully deploys the cmd check on github actions for Max and Ubuntu but fails for windows.  The part that fails is `run: julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("WildBootTests")'`, which installs the `WildBootTests.jl` package via the shell.

Does anyone have an idea why the installation of `WildBootTests.jl` fails on windows, but not on Mac and Ubuntu?

You can find more information on the workflow here: https://github.com/s3alfisc/fwildclusterboot/actions/runs/1583895387

Thanks for your help!

```
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/master/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]

name: R-CMD-check

jobs:

  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: 'release'}
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'devel', http-user-agent: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'release'}
          - {os: ubuntu-latest,   r: 'oldrel-1'}

    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      R_KEEP_PKG_SOURCE: yes

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
        with:
          r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}
          http-user-agent: ${{ matrix.config.http-user-agent }}
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1
        with:
          extra-packages: rcmdcheck

      # custom code starts here 
      # install julia
      - uses: julia-actions/setup-julia@v1
      # add julia to renviron
      - name: Create and populate .Renviron file
        run: echo JULIA_BINDIR= "${{ env.juliaLocation }}" >> ~/.Renviron
      # install WildBootTests.jl
      - name: install WildBootTests.jl
        run: julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("WildBootTests")'
      # custom code ends here

      - uses: r-lib/actions/check-r-package@v1

      - name: Show testthat output
        if: always()
        run: find check -name 'testthat.Rout*' -exec cat '{}' \; || true
        shell: bash

      - name: Upload check results
        if: failure()
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@main
        with:
          name: ${{ runner.os }}-r${{ matrix.config.r }}-results
          path: check
```

**Update**: If I include the line `shell: bash` under the `run: julia -e` statements, package installation does not fail on windows.

Hence, the added part needs to look like this:

```
      # custom code starts here 
      # install julia
      - uses: julia-actions/setup-julia@v1
      # add julia to renviron
      - name: Create and populate .Renviron file
        run: echo JULIA_BINDIR= "${{ env.juliaLocation }}" >> ~/.Renviron
        shell: bash
      # install WildBootTests.jl
      - name: install WildBootTests.jl
        run: julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("WildBootTests")'
        shell: bash
      # custom code ends here
```

Comment: It seems that Powershell is looking for an environment variable called `WildBootTests` that doesn't exist. I'm not sure why this would be the case. Would it work if you simply define `WildBootTests = "WildBootTests"` as an environment variable under the `env` section?

Comment: You are right, there is a problem with the shell, which I managed to fix by putting `shell: bash` under the `run: julia -e...` part. I found this solution in the [Julia forum](https://github.com/julia-actions/setup-julia/issues/23), maybe it helps others to understand what is going on. I will update my answer later today!